# High Disk I/O spike followed by jumps in memory on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, memory, nginx, ruby

I'm running a server on Ubuntu with Ruby, Sinatra, Unicorn and Nginx. I start everything up and it builds to about 66%, where it remains for a while. Then after a few hours, there's a large Disk I/O spike, and a permanent increase in memory usage. This then continues to rise in jumps as time goes on, with no apparent further large spikes of Disk I/O.

These graphs are from DigitalOcean's Graphs page - they host the instance.

[image]

Checking my Unicorn logs, and my personal logs that I make on any activity within my Ruby application, there doesn't seem to be any major event occurring at times when those spikes occur. Activity appears to be fairly standard. This is also true when the jumps in memory usage occur.

It seems that perhaps something's happening outside of my application that's causing the Disk I/O spike, and subsequent memory rises.

I'm wondering if there's anything else I could be looking at to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `top` sorted by resident memory?

Comment: I haven't. That memory tab on the bottom right, when I switch to it, shows that the memory usage is almost entirely Ruby, at 95%.

Comment: This being so, you must look out for a bug in your application - most likely an endless loop.